# How can we use carbon diffforhumans with array

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I am using my user controller to return his liked documents and it is returning in array rather than object so i want to use carbon diffforhumans with my date field how can we use it .Here is my controllers code

```
public function myfavourites()
{
    // echo "This is myfavourites";
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    // $liked_post =  Like::all()->where('user_id', $user_id);

    return view('user.myfavourites')->with('likes', Like::where('user_id', $user_id)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(12));
}
```

and here is my blade code

```
<h6 class="text-muted">Published <b>{{ $like->document['created_at']->diffForHumans() }}</b></h6>
```

here h6 is in foreach loop where i am looping throw the all liked documents by the user.
i have relation with my like model to with my document model
here is my relationship function

```
public function document()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Document');
    }
```

whats the solution of this problem either i have to return likes in object form if yes then how?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Carbon class to use diffForHumans(),

```
 <h6 class="text-muted">Published <b>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($like->document['created_at'])->diffForHumans() }}</b></h6>
```

if its an array you'll either need to loop through each item in the array or use a key for single item

```
@foreach($like->document as $key => $value)
 <h6 class="text-muted">Published <b>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($value['created_at'])->diffForHumans() }}</b></h6>
@endforeach
```

or through single key

```
<h6 class="text-muted">Published <b>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($like->document[0]['created_at'])->diffForHumans() }}</b></h6>
```

Comment: Thanks Aditya Thakur this works when i delete [0] and it became like this
<h6 class="text-muted">Published <b>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($like->document['created_at'])->diffForHumans() }}</b></h6>

Comment: @AdnanAli you're welcome, sorry i was in impression that there were multiple documents, but since you figured it out, its all good,